# How to get sentiment score for a word in a given dataset

Tags: nlp, dataset, sentiment-analysis, bert-language-model

I have a sentiment analysis dataset that is labeled in three categories: positive, negative, and neutral. I also have a list of words (mostly nouns), for which I want to calculate the sentiment value, to understand "how" (positively or negatively) these entities were talked about in the dataset. I have read some online resources like blogs and thought about a couple of approaches for calculating the sentiment score for a particular word X.

1. Calculate how many data instances (sentences) which have the word X in those, have "positive" labels, have "negative" labels, and "neutral" labels. Then, calculate the weighted average sentiment for that word.
2. Take a generic untrained BERT architecture, and then train it using the dataset. Then, pass each word from the list to that trained model to get the sentiment scores for the word.

Does any of these approaches make sense? If so, can you suggest some related works that I can look at?
If these approaches don't make sense, could you please advise how I can calculate the sentiment score for a word, in a given dataset?

Comment: I downvoted this question as it appears to be a question for Computer Science [https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/125101/] or another Community Forum...

Answer (score 0):

The first method will suffer from the same drawbacks as other bag-of-words models do. Consider that you have a dataset of movie reviews with their sentiment scores, and you want to find the sentiment for a particular actor called X. A label for a sample like "X's acting was the only good thing in an otherwise bad movie" will be negative, but the sentiment towards X is positive. A simple approach like the first one can't handle such cases.

The second approach also does not make much sense, as the BERT models may not perform well without context. You can try using weakly supervised learning which can help in creating token-level labels. Read section 3.3 for [this paper](https://aclanthology.org/2021.semeval-1.127/) to get an idea about this. Disclaimer: I'm one of the authors of this paper.